# Deprecation warning in Symfony 2.7

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.7

I recently updated to Symfony 2.7 and ran into this issue. It is giving me this deprecation error.

```
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition::setFactoryMethod(getRepository) is deprecated since version 2.6 and will be removed in 3.0. Use Definition::setFactory() instead

Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition::setFactoryService(doctrine.orm.entity_manager) is deprecated since version 2.6 and will be removed in 3.0. Use Definition::setFactory() instead
```

Seems like culprit is this configuration.

```
ac_queue.failed.job.repository:
    class: Acme\Bundle\QueueBundle\Repository\FailedJob
    factory_service: doctrine.orm.entity_manager
    factory_method: getRepository
    arguments: ['AcmeQueueBundle:FailedJob']
    public: false
```

What is the right way to do this now in Symfony 2.7 now?

Comment: **The error message just told you the right way to do it** when you move to 3.0 the `Definition::setFactoryMethod(getRepository)` method will be removed. So as soon as possible, make the suggested changes

Comment: It's stated in your error itself:- `Use Definition::setFactory()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to transform `factory_service` and `factory_method` to the `factory` parameter:

```
ac_queue.failed.job.repository:
    class: Acme\Bundle\QueueBundle\Repository\FailedJob
    factory: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager, getRepository]
    arguments: ['AcmeQueueBundle:FailedJob']
    public: false
```

Answer (score 1):

KNPUniversity covered this deprecation error among others in this article:

http://knpuniversity.com/blog/upgrading-symfony-2.7#you-need-to-upgrade-sensio-distribution-bundle